# SOAPUI 5.2.1 : SQLServer Exception in JDBC Request

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, soapui

Driver:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Conection String:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=abc;user=sa&password=abc123
```

I'm getting SQLServer Exception when testing connection,

```
Can't get the Connection for specified properties;
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'sa&password=abc123'.
ClientConnectionId:12f87cf5-0018-46d3-9309-a2f81004ddf8
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to sql DB from soapUI using connection string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33568902/how-to-connect-to-sql-db-from-soapui-using-connection-string)

Comment: problem was **&** in connection string.

Answer (score 0):

You should use url delimiters (1-?, all the rest-& instead of ";"), database name comes just as path after the port number:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/yourdatebase?user=sa&password=abc123
```